# dynamic import for file using wildmatch

Tags: qlikview

```
dataimport:
LOAD  
  @1 AS CoCd,
  @2 AS Period,
  @3 AS [Doc. Date],
  @4 AS [Pstng Date],
  @6 AS Reference,
  @7 AS DocumentNo,
  @8 AS Crcy,
  @9 AS Year,
  @10 AS [Doc. Type]
FROM
  \\cagta5454\Indirect\Clients\\zz Work-in-Progress\2014\data\*_110_*GLDetl* 
;
```

I want help in dynamic import for a file

currently file is located at

```
\\cagta5454\Indirect\Clients\\zz Work-in-Progress\2014\data\*_110_*GLDetl*
```

I am looking for a way so that I can able to do dynamic import

something like creating a variable

`$dataLocation = \\cagta5454\Indirect\Clients\\zz Work-in-Progress\2014\data\*_`

and `$datafiles = '110','121','141'`

so that instead of using number for the file containing data ,  I can use  a variable

Answer (score 0):

The `for each ... next` function can work for you. For more examples you can always make reference to the QV Help file `c:\Program Files\QlikView\English.chm` or the online version of it at https://help.qlik.com/en-US/#

```
let dataFiles = '110, 121, 141';

for each i in $(datafiles)
    let dataLocation = '\\cagta5454\Indirect\Clients\\zz Work-in-Progress\2014\data\*_' & '$(i)' & '_*GLDetl*';

    dataimport:
    Load  
        @1  AS CoCd,
        @2  AS Period,
        @3  AS [Doc. Date],
        @4  AS [Pstng Date],
        @6  AS Reference,
        @7  AS DocumentNo,
        @8  AS Crcy,
        @9  AS Year,
        @10 AS [Doc. Type]
    From
        $(dataLocation)
    ;   

next
```